# Segmentation fault when trying to add hex to binary file

Tags: segmentation-fault

I am able to edit in a hex editor a linux executable and replace a char with my own, but it gives me segmentation fault when i try to add a new character.

Comment: What segfaults, the hex editor or the executable after you edit it?

Comment: the executable, when i try to run it on a linux box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you expect?

An ELF executable has a lot of internal structure, and modifying or adding random bytes to it causes that structure to become corrupt (self inconsistent).

When the dynamic loader encounteres such corrupt ELF binary, it simply crashes. While *some* corruptions may not cause an immediate crash, that doesn't mean you can do this and expect things to work.

Some "post-link" editing of ELF binaries is possible, but it requires that one understands the [ELF format](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), and preserves its validity.